# Python url form submission not working

Tags: python

Using Python, I'm trying to submit a form to a url and get a response.. This is what I'm doing:

```
import urllib, urllib2

data = {
    'date': '300186',
    'search_type': 'state',
    'search_state': 'NY',
}

req = urllib2.Request(
    url='https://services.aamc.org/20/mcat/findsite', 
    data=urllib.urlencode(data), 
    headers={"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
)

response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
print(response.read())
```

However, I'm getting this:

```
<script>location.replace('https://services.aamc.org/20/mcat');</script>
```

Which I guess simply means a redirection to the main page... Did I miss something, or is the AAMC website doing this on purpose..?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

So I'm basically trying to connect to url "https://services.aamc.org/20/mcat/findsite/findexam?date=3001816search_type=state&search_state=NY"

and this works fine when I enter this on my browser.. So I guess there's nothing wrong with the query

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you have already log into the site from your browser. So the site may have put a cookie in your browser to identify you on next attemp an automatically log you (as do stackoverflow.com). But when you send the request from the python script, there is nothing to identify you, and you are redirected to login page (I tried the URL you show and was ...).

You will have to do the connection in your script to pass the login page. But for it to work, you will have to add a `HttpCookieProcessor` handler to an `Opener`

```
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
```

then use

```
response = opener.open(req)
```

instead of

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```